# wpf DataGridTextColumn refactoring

Tags: wpf, datagrid, dry

I am using a DataGrid in a WPF app that has several (literally one for each day of the week) columns which differ only in their data index. A sample of the xaml is below.

How can I refactor this into something more DRY?

Cheers,
Berryl

SAMPLE XAML (two of seven columns):

```
<dg:DataGridTextColumn 
    Header="{Binding Source={StaticResource spy}, Path=DataContext[0].EventDate,   Converter={StaticResource dateConv}}" 
    CellStyle="{StaticResource DataEntryCellStyle}" Width="60" CanUserResize="False"
    Binding="{Binding Allocations[0].Amount, Converter={StaticResource amtConv}}"  
                               />
<dg:DataGridTextColumn 
    Header="{Binding Source={StaticResource spy}, Path=DataContext[1].EventDate, Converter={StaticResource dateConv}}" 
    CellStyle="{StaticResource DataEntryCellStyle}" Width="60" CanUserResize="False"
    Binding="{Binding Allocations[1].Amount, Converter={StaticResource amtConv}}"  
                               />
```

== EDITED ADD'L INFO @ JALFP ===

Compiler complains that the target type is not a framework element when building

```
<Style x:Key="dayOfWeekColumn" TargetType="dg:DataGridTextColumn" >
    <Setter Property="CanUserResize" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="CanUserSort" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="60" />
    <Setter Property="CellStyle" Value="{StaticResource dataEntryGridCellStyle}" />
</Style>
```

I don't see anything that looks like a ColumnStyle either. What property would I set this style to in the xaml for the DataGridTextColumn?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can create your own class which inherits from DataGridTextColumn and add a new DependencyProperty DayIndex (from 0 to 6). Then in this class you could to the initialization you're doing in the XAML...

But I'm not sure it will be a really better and more maintainable solution...

Comment: Hi Jalfp, and thanks for the reply. This makes sense, although I was hoping some clever use of styles and other WPF techniques I am not familiar with yet might be easier.

Comment: You can use a Style which targets The DataGridTextColumn type and set CellStyle, Width and CanUserResize property.

Comment: Hi Jalfp. I tried this without success; added code and comments in edit of the original posting. Can you please take a look? Cheers!